# Removing an element through the parentNode.removeChild throws a DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild, domexception

I have code which is roughly as follows (I removed some parts, as they are irrelevant):

```
Library.focus = function(event) {
    var element, paragraph;

    element = event.srcElement;

    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerText = element.innerText;

    element.parentNode.insertBefore(paragraph, element);        // Line #1
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);                    // Line #2
};
```

The issue I have, is that the last call which I've numbered as line #2 throws this:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Note that the previous line #1 works fine, and inserts the paragraph node before it.
Element is an existing element, and both element.parentNode and element.parentNode.removeChild exist as well.

I find this illogical, as element is by definition a child of its parentNode.
Maybe StackOverflow will be able to help me out, here?

Comment: i dont think element = event.srcElement; is returning what you are expecting, so first console.log(element); after, element = event.srcElement; and let us know what it is returning.

Comment: What is the `Library`? Because when I tried ["what I think it is"](http://jsfiddle.net/jPXr3/1/), it worked?

Comment: @shreedhar It does return what I'm expecting. It's an h1 with contentEditable (hence the focus event).

Comment: Both "srcElement" and "innerText" are Internet Explorer things that won't work in Firefox and (possibly) WebKit.

Comment: @pointy I'm working in Chrome, so it isn't an issue (they exist and work fine in Webkit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild):

> If child is actually not a child of the element node, the method
>   throws an exception.      This will also happen if child was in fact a
>   child of element at the time of the call, but was removed by an event
>   handler invoked in the course of trying to remove the element (eg,
>   blur.)

I can reproduce this error in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz3XM/1/)

Basically, you focus the element, which triggers a remove, which triggers a blur, which moves the element, which makes the element not the parent anymore.

Comment: Ahh, this is probably what's happening (I have a blur event handler as well). Thanks! What would be the solution to this, though?

Comment: [Scroll down to the Lime.blur event](https://github.com/cyrilmengin/lime/blob/master/src/lime.js) (the LimeDown method just returns a paragraph node)

Comment: @AlvinWong you commented out the blur handler

Comment: @user697108 I cannot really understand what these functions are trying to do. Maybe set some flag on the element before removing so the blur handler doesn't attempt to do anything with the element because it was triggered by `.removeChild` internals instead of actual UI blur.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to modify, in an onblur handler, the same node you're trying to remove in another handler (eg onfocus, keydown etc) then the first call to `removeChild` will fire the onblur handler before actually removing the node. 
If the onblur handler then modifies the node so that its parent changes, control will return from the onblur handler to the `removeChild` call in your onfocus handler which will then try to remove the node and fail with the exception you describe.

Any amount of checking for the presence of the child before calling `removeChild` in your onfocus handler will be fruitless, since those checks will happen before the onblur handler is triggered.

Apart from re-arranging your event handling and node modifications, your best bet is probably to just handle the exception in a try catch block.

The following code will show how the onblur event handler runs before `removeChild` in onfocus actually removes the child. It is also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBs4b/11/)

html

```
<div id="iParent">
    <input id="i">
</div>
```

js

```
var input = document.querySelector("#i"),
inputParent = document.querySelector('#iParent');

input.onblur = function() {
    console.log('onblur : input ' + (input.parentNode ? 'has' : 'doesnt have') 
            + ' a parent BEFORE delete');
    try {
        inputParent.removeChild(input);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('onblur : removeChild failed, input ' 
                + (input.parentNode ? 'has' : 'doesnt have') + ' a parent');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('onblur : child removed');
};

input.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('onfocus : input ' + (input.parentNode ? 'has' : 'doesnt have') 
            + ' a parent BEFORE delete');
    try {
        inputParent.removeChild(input);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('onfocus : removeChild failed, input ' 
                + (input.parentNode ? 'has' : 'doesnt have') + ' a parent');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('onfocus : child removed');
};​
```

Console output after focusing on the input field will be

```
onfocus : input has a parent BEFORE delete
onblur : input has a parent BEFORE delete
onblur : child removed
onfocus : removeChild failed, input doesnt have a parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass the event as parameter for Library.focus function. it will work.

```
Library.focus = function() {
    var element, paragraph;

    element = event.srcElement;

    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerText = element.innerText;

    element.parentNode.insertBefore(paragraph, element);        // Line #1
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);                    // Line #2
};
```

Comment: `event` is a non-standard global object in IE and Chrome only.

Comment: @RobW even im trying figure out, why its working after removing event parameter. any idea sir?

Comment: What's working? You have only shown an isolated piece of code, whose behaviour depends on how you implement it. For instance, `<p onclick="Library.focus(event)">xxx</p>` would achieve the same effect. EDIT response to below comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/jPXr3/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jPXr3/1/ check this link sir, if i add event parameter to the function, it produces an error, so kindly clarify me sir.